# Slick query produces mapping error

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I have a join query in slick but there when I join `Addresses` table the condition of join requires `UserSettings` (ust) but I cannot get the table from 'get' function. The `getOrElse` returns the correct table but what to pass in the function parameters.

It generates the following error

```
No matching Shape found.
Slick does not know how to map the given types.
Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List).
 Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel
    Source type: Int
  Unpacked type: Any
    Packed type: P2
```

Here is my Slick query

```
var queryTest = Users.drop((pageNo - 1) * noOfItemsPerPage).take(noOfItemsPerPage).joinLeft(UserStatesOfInterest).on {
  case (usr, usi) => (usr.id === usi.userId)
  } .joinLeft(UserImpactAreas).on {
  case ((usr, usi), uia) => (usr.id === uia.userId)
  } .joinLeft(UserSettings).on {
  case (((usr, usi), uia), ust) => (usr.id === ust.userId)
  }.joinLeft(Addresses).on {
  case ((((usr, usi), uia), ust), adr) =>  (ust.getOrElse(0).contactAddress === adr.id)
  }
```

Comment: Need your slick tables to understand what mapping you need

Comment: why are you doing getOrElse